# Getting Latest Records

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sorting

I have list of records in a Xml file,where each record as its date of creation.Can you please suggest me an efficient way in getting the latest two records.

Xml File can be taught of as below:

```
<Records>
    <Record>
        <RecordID>1<RecordID>
        <CreationDate>Apr 01, 2011 10:15 <CreationDate>
   <Record>
   <Record>
        <RecordID>2<RecordID>
        <CreationDate>Jan 12, 2011 10:15<CreationDate>
   <Record>
   <Record>
       <RecordID>3<RecordID>
       <CreationDate>Feb 12, 2011 09:00<CreationDate>
   <Record>
         .
         .
         .
         .
   many such records...
<Records>
```

Will take all this xml into a list,but then can u tell me a efficient way in extracting latest two records out of the list.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should be a bit more precise and explain what language you're using and what data type you'll be converting your xml into.

Comment: Hi Antoine, I am using C#.net and using visual studio's create schema to create schema file and xsd.exe to generate entities out of the xml.  public partial class Records {
    
    private RecordsRecord[] recordField;
    
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Record")]
    public RecordsRecord[] Record {
        get {
            return this.recordField;
        }
        set {
            this.recordField = value;
        }
    }
}    and  public partial class RecordsRecord {
    
    private byte recordIDField;
    
    private string creationDateField;

Comment: Sorry functions are not readable in above comment so adding again    public partial class Records {
    
    private RecordsRecord[] recordField;
    
    
    public RecordsRecord[] Record {
        get {
            return this.recordField;
        }
        set {
            this.recordField = value;
        }
    }
}

Comment: and one more:  public partial class RecordsRecord {
    
    private byte recordIDField;
    
    private string creationDateField;
    

    public byte RecordID {
        get {
            return this.recordIDField;
        }
        set {
            this.recordIDField = value;
        }
    }
    

    public string CreationDate {
        get {
            return this.creationDateField;
        }
        set {
            this.creationDateField = value;
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the creation date as a DateTime object and not as a string. Implement a comparison method in your Record class that compares the creation dates. Then if you store your records in a list you should be able to sort it. In the example below the latest records will be at the end, so if you want them just reverse the list.

```
List<Records> recordList = parseXml(); // populate your list
recordList.Sort(new Comparison<Record>(Record.Comparison)); // sort in creation date ascending order
recordList.Revers(); // reverse the elements in the list

Record[] the2latest = new Record[2]{recordList[0], recordList[1]};

public partial class Record
{
   public static int Comparison(Record r1, Record r2)
    {
        return DateTime.Compare(r1.creationDate, r2.creationDate);
    }
}
```